# I need my strategy to check 80 previous bars for criteria x

Tags: pine-script, trading

i have a question on which I can not find any answer on web sources.

I need my strategy to check 80 previous bars for criteria x.

Can I shorten the code instead of writing like these: (below example of my code)

Thank you so much for your help
Like this:

x = y[1]>low or y[2]>low.....

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! please read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how to ask questions on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution

```
var x = false
for i=1 to 80
    x := x or y[i]>low
```